# django. работа с User

Tags: python, django

Привет ребята, начал изучать django. Прикрутил в проекте регистрацию, теперь хочу реализовать добавление статей и файлов от конкретного юзера, в итоге немного запутался в логике. Я должен создать модель и связать ее через ForeignKey с моделью User?  я в правильном направлении мыслю? пока у меня это не выходит

Comment: Добавьте код, или киньте ошибка.

Comment: В правильном. И про подобное есть в [официальном учебнике](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/intro/tutorial01.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, как вы и говорите, связывать свою модель пользователя с моделью `django.contrib.auth.models.User` через `ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)`, по этому способу можно найти много информации в интернете, особенно в англоязычном.

Также можно воспользоваться наследованием классов и унаследоваться от абстрактного класса `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`, в этом случае нужно будет в `settings.py` прописать путь к нашему классу пользователя `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.Profile'` и указать бекэнд `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`

Плюсы данного подхода:

- Отсутствие необходимости создавать несколько таблиц
- Избавление от лишней связи между таблицами (вытекает из первого)
- Возможность использования стандартного механизма авторизации со своей моделью

Как это выглядит?

```
#user/model.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models


class Profile(AbstractUser):
    about_me = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('about me'), blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', verbose_name=_('avatar'), blank=True)
    ...

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profiles'
        verbose_name = _('user profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('user profiles')
```

---

```
#settings.py

....

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.Profile'

...
```

Что касается загрузки файлов, рекомендую попробовать [решения из документации](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/file-uploads.html#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).

Думаю в вашем случае сработает вот так:

```
# views.py
def cabinet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.profile_user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect(reverse(cabinet))
    return render(request, 'cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

При работе с файлами не забывайте указывать параметр *enctype* в теге формы.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

я бы попробовал Вашу вью вот так:

```
def cabinet(request):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES,  instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.profile_user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        obj.save()
        return redirect(reverse(cabinet))
    return render(request, 'cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

Возможно несколько запутано, но у меня работает. Сам еще начинающий.

Comment: спасибо, не особо запутано